# Lognormal random numbers in specific range in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, preconditions

I want to develop a lognormal distribution with range [0.42,1.19], whose few elements are given as `D=[1.19,1.00,0.84,0.71,0.59,0.50,0.42]`. The mean should be `0.84` and standard deviation as small as possible. Also given is that the 90% of cdf (=90% of the grains) lies between `0.59 and 1.19`.

Once I know all the elements of this lognormal distribution which incorporate the given conditions I can find its pdf, which is what I require. Here are simple steps I tried:

```
D=[1.19,1.00,0.84,0.71,0.59,0.50,0.42];

s=0.30; % std dev of the lognormal distribution

m=0.84; % mean of the lognormal distribution

mu=log(m^2/sqrt(s^2+m^2)); % mean of the associated normal dist.

sigma=sqrt(log((s^2/m^2)+1)); % std dev of the associated normal dist.

[r,c]=size(D);

for i=1:c

D_normal(i)=mu+(sigma.*randn(1));

w(i)=(D_normal(i)-mu)/sigma; % the probability or the wt. percentage

end

sizes=exp(D_normal);
```

Comment: I would suggest adding the code you have so far to your question. That will better help us help you.

Comment: Please format your posted code - you can do so by highlighting and clicking the 'ones-and-zeros' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the statistics toolbox and you want to draw random values from the lognormal distribution, you can simply call [LOGNRND](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/lognrnd.html). If you want to  know the density of the lognormal distribution with a given mean and sigma at a specific value, you use [LOGNPDF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/lognpdf.html).

Since you're calculating weights, you may be looking for the density. These would be, in your example:

```
weights = lognpdf([1.19,1.00,0.84,0.71,0.59,0.50,0.42],0.84,0.3)

weights =
     0.095039     0.026385     0.005212   0.00079218   6.9197e-05   5.6697e-06   2.9244e-07
```

**EDIT**

If you want to know what percentage of grains falls into the range of 0.59 to 1.19, you use [LOGNCDF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/logncdf.html):

```
100*diff(logncdf([0.59,1.19],0.84,0.3))
ans =
       1.3202
```

That's not a lot. If you plot the distribution, you'll notice that the lognormal distribution with your values peaks a bit above 2

```
x = 0:0.01:10;
figure
plot(x,lognpdf(x,0.84,0.3))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I don't want to pick random value from the grain sizes i.e. from the lognormal distribution. I want the probability of their occurrences given their mean and standard deviation, and also given range of the distribution. Further I know that 90% of the grains (by weight) fall between 1.19 and 0.59 while the rest falls between 0.59 to 0.42 grain sizes.

Comment: @Harpreet: Have you looked at my edit? Have you plotted the distribution? The lognormal distribution peaks at `exp(0.84)`, not at 0.84, and thus only 1.3% of the values fall into the range where you'd expect 90%. Also, what do you mean with the probability of the occurrences? If it's the value of the probability density function, i.e. the probability of drawing a specific value from a distribution, I have calculated that for you already as `weights`.

Comment: Jonas, I did look at all what you said. I mean pdf (when I said probability of occurrences). I am actually not able to see any sign of lognormal distribution in the given data. Its more like a zigzag noise in shape. How does peak occurs at exp(0.84)? Shouldn't it be log(0.84) instead? To avoid entangling in complexity of communication further, my question is: 
I want to develop a lognormal distribution with range [0.30,1.19], whose few elements are given in 'D'. The mean should be 0.84 and standard deviation as small as possible. Also given is that the 90% of cdf lies between 0.59 and 1.19.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking to generate truncated lognormal random numbers. If my assumption is correct you can either use the [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) or [inverse transform sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to generate the necessary samples. Caveat: Rejection sampling is very inefficient if your bounds are very far from the mean.

**Rejection Sampling**

If x ~ LogNormal(mu,sigma) I(lb < x < ub )

Then generate, x ~ LogNormal(mu,sigma) and accept the draw if lb < x < ub.

**Inverse Transform Sampling**

If x ~ LogNormal(mu,sigma) I(lb < x < ub ) then

CDF(x) = phi((log(x) - mu)/sigma) /( phi((log(ub) - mu)/sigma) - phi((log(lb) - mu)/sigma))

Generate, u ~ Uniform(0,1).

Set, CDF(x) = u and invert for x.

In other words,

x = exp( mu + sigma * phi_inverse( u * ( phi((log(ub) - mu)/sigma) - phi((log(lb) - mu)/sigma)) ) )

Comment: My lognormal distribution is truncated. These grain sizes given here are picked from the whole sample available. Though grain sizes follow lognormal distribution but I am not sure if these truncated values from the entire lot would follow the same distribution. I dont want my random numbers to be truncated. They should be between 0 and 1 representing my weight percentages.

Comment: You should consider using standard terminology to avoid confusion. When you say weight percentages do you mean the probability that a grain's size falls between two values or do you mean the pdf associated with a particular grain size? You say that your distribution is truncated but then the last but one line you say you do not want your random numbers to be truncated. Those are contradictory statements.

Comment: I mean pdf associated with a particular grain size. 
I want all my random numbers (pdf) to be generated considering this given distribution as complete. Though more values WITHIN the distribution (not outside the given range) could be added, however I don't know how to do that.

Comment: In that case, you should do what Jonas suggested. If you want your pdf to be that of a truncated lognormal then compute the pdf as suggested by Jonas but then divide by the value by ( phi((log(ub) - mu)/sigma) - phi((log(lb) - mu)/sigma))

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what are 'phi', 'ub' and 'lb'. Can you tell what are they?

Comment: phi is normalcdf with mean 0 and std dev 1. lb and ub are the lower and upper bounds for your random variable.