# Generate logormal random numbers within range matlab

Tags: matlab

we have data that follows he lognormal distribution, knowing it's mean = 5.0163 and standard deviation = 1.0571 we want to generate and draw n (6000) sample **within range** (3:7.9) that follows the same distribution with monte-carlo method
we have this code but it doesn't output samples in the desired range (all samples are smaller than the lower limit)

```
Data = [ 3 3 3 3 3.3 3.3 3.6 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 3.9 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.5 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.1 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6.3 6.3 6.3 6.3 6.3 6.3 6.3 6.6 6.6 6.6 6.6 6.9 6.9 6.9 7.8];
%draw Lognormal Fit of the data
histfit(Data,[],'lognormal');
% lognormal curve parameters
LN = lognfit(Data);
m=LN(1);
s=LN(2);
% mean and stanard diviation of the associated normal dist.
mu=log(m^2/sqrt(s^2+m^2));
sigma=sqrt(log((s^2/m^2)+1));
%generate random numbers
for i = 1 : 100
X = lognrnd(mu,sigma)
if ((X>=3)&&(X<=7.9))
 X;
end
end
```

Comment: That `if` statement of yours isn't doing anything, whether the statement is true or false. You are calling `X;` which does absolutely naught.

Comment: You can omit that loop by using `X = lognrnd(mu,sigma,100,1)` if you want to have 100 values. Btw: mu = 0.45, sigma = 0.136 in your example code.

Comment: [Take a look at the documentation for logical indexing, first example](http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?refresh=true)

Comment: @Matthias, you are right mu and sigma weren't correct. now we can generate the 6000 samples using 'X = lognrnd(mu,sigma,6000,1)'. What about limiting the generated values to b in the range from 3 to 7.9

Comment: @user3332603 you can "filter" your results using logical indexing: `X( (X >= 3) & (X <= 7.9) )`, but this will obviously drop the values that are not within your given interval - giving you less than the 100 values.

Comment: Possible duplicates or references: [SO - How to generate random numbers of lognormal distribution within specific range in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070183/how-to-generate-random-numbers-of-lognormal-distribution-within-specific-range-i), [MATLAB Central - Log normal distribution between two value](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/337511)

Comment: @MatthiasW. I'm not sure [Lognormal random numbers in specific range in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3070183/8239061) is really a duplicate; while that OP also wants a truncated Lognormal, they also state they want to "_minimize the standard deviation_" which is different from this question's OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to guarantee samples from a [Lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) will fall within a certain (finite) range as the support for the distribution is unbounded (all positive real numbers). However, we can invoke MATLAB's `truncate` function to easily deal with this issue (see below). One caveat is that the resulting samples aren't from a Lognormal distribution anymore (they are from a truncated Lognormal).

**Parameterization:** Note that if X ~ Normal(mu,sigma), then if Y = ln(X), Y ~ Lognormal(mu,sigma).  Thus, the Lognormal is often parameterized by the associated Normal distribution. The mean, E[Y] is *not* equal to mu.

This is illustrated by the code below.

```
mu = 5; 
sigma = 1;
pd = makedist('Lognormal',mu,sigma)
Y = random(pd,50000,1);                 % 50000 Lognormal samples
X = log(Y);  

>> mean(X)                              
ans =
    4.9922
>> std(X)
ans =
    1.0007
```

**Restriction to the range [a,b]:**
Given the parameters mu and sigma obtained from fitting the Lognormal, then restriction to an given interval, [a,b] is simple with MATLAB's probability distribution objects (introduced in R2013a).

```
mu = 2.5;       % Assume mu & sigma found from fitting 
sigma = 1.4;
pd = makedist('Lognormal',mu,sigma);    % Creates the Lognormal distribution object

a = 10;
b = 100;
N = 10000;
pdT = truncate(pd,a,b);              % Truncates to the interval [a,b]

Y = random(pdT,N,1);                 % Generate samples from truncated Lognormal
```

The difference is clear.

[image: Lognormal & Truncated Lognormal]

```
W = random(pd,N,1);                  % Generate samples from Lognormal 

figure
s(1) = subplot(2,1,1)
histogram(Y,'Normalization','pdf')
xlim([0,125])
s(2) = subplot(2,1,2)
histogram(W,'Normalization','pdf','FaceColor','g','FaceAlpha',0.35)
xlim([0 125])
title(s(2),'Lognormal(\mu=2.5,\sigma=1.4)')
title(s(1),'Lognormal(\mu=2.5,\sigma=1.4) truncated to [10,100]')
```